# Tabs, but no tab selected by default?

Tags: navigation, tabs

I am working on an view that allows you to define a list of matching criteria and then allows you to view various reports.

This is what I have till now:

[image]

Now, you would probably want to ask... if you are using tabs, why on earth you are not preselecting one?

There are two reasons:

1. Each report requires some other data input (which may vary depending on the report)
2. All report are equally important and I need to make sure that one report does not get favoured to others (let's say the leftmost one).

One thing to consider is that there are going to be pre-saved views, where a set of criteria is matched with a report (so the report is going to be pre-selected with all the inputs needed), so there could be some learning here, but the user is still able to create one view on his own and not get confused.

**So that's my specific context, I guess my main "broader" question is:
In scenarios where one state works well with tabs, but another state requires you to not have any tab selected, are there better alternative to tabs?**

Comment: would still use tabs. or if youre into that sort of thing you can use accordion

Answer (score 5):

I think your issue is that tabs probably *aren't* the best option to take. A tab should be showing different content directly related to the one 'parent' item, whereas what your requirement seems to be is to create some criteria and then generate a report(s). - There is a flow to this journey - select criteria > generate report, so you should fit the controls to the user journey.

I would suggest stepping away from the tab metaphor and think of it from a different angle. You have criteria, once selected there is a report that you want to produce. You don't (as far as I can tell) have a requirement to directly compare one report to another - they are separate reports used for different purposes. Therefore you don't really need to switch between reports in the way tabs would work.

I suggest something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3nWZf.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

However this isn't so scalable, so you might want to change the various buttons to be a dropdown list with a 'generate' button that triggers the report chosen, but for the purposes of this example it should get the idea across.